# delete/modify selected text in EdiText in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I entered text in an EditText while designing a form filling app. Now, if i select part of that text, and wish to delete/modify it, I am not getting how to do it. All other options show how to clear entire textbox. How to clear just selected text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   EditText inputText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    String inputString=inputText.getText().toString();


    //To get the selected String
    int selectionStart=inputText.getSelectionStart();
    int selectionEnd=inputText.getSelectionEnd();
    String selectedText = inputString.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);

    if(!selectedText.isEmpty())
    {
        //Modify the selected StringHere
        String modifiedString="...your modification logic here...";

        //If you wish to delete the selected text
        String selectionDeletedString=inputString.replace(selectedText,"");
        inputText.setText(selectionDeletedString);

        //If you wish to modify the selected text
        String selectionModifiedString=inputString.replace(selectedText,modifiedString);
        inputText.setText(selectionModifiedString);

    }
```

Comment: what if the user is selecting a word which is being repeated multiple times and the user wants to replace only one word??

Comment: @MithileshIzardar Try the answer I just posted. It gets two substrings around the selection and concats them.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but helped a lot with a few modifications to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the string with

```
String fromEditText = editText.getText();
```

Now, you can do with string whatever you want and then put it back like

```
editText.setText(myString);
```

For operations with strings google working with strings and chars java on google.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public void modifyText(View view ) {
    if (view instanceof EditText) {

        if(view.getText().toString().equals("Selected text")){
           view.setText("Your Text");
        }
     }

        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {

            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);

            modifyText(innerView);
        }
    }   
}
```

call this in your activity `modifyText(findViewById(R.id.rootView));`

This will modify all `EditText` in the current activity

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the best solution.

```
String contents = editText.getText().toString(), newText;
newText = contents.substring(0, noteEdit.getSelectionStart()) + 
contents.substring(editText.getSelectionEnd(), contents.length());
editText.setText(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Edit Selection

An easy and best(maybe) way of modifying the selected text.

```
int start = descriptionBox.getSelectionStart();
int end = descriptionBox.getSelectionEnd();
String modifiedText = "*" + descriptionBox.getText().subSequence(start, end) + "*";
descriptionBox.getText().replace(start, end, modifiedText);
```

**Input Text** ( '|' indicate selection )

```
hello |world|
```

**Output Text**

```
hello *world*
```

---

## Delete Selection

All you have to do is replace the start and end of selection with empty String.

```
int start = descriptionBox.getSelectionStart();
int end = descriptionBox.getSelectionEnd();
descriptionBox.getText().replace(start, end, "");
```